# Symmetry factors for feynman diagrams from complex scalar interaction term

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, symmetry, feynman-diagrams

My question regards a quantum field theory with an interaction term $${\mathcal{L_{int}}=-\frac{\lambda}{4}\phi^\dagger}^2 \phi^2.$$ It's claimed in the solutions to a problem sheet that the one-loop correction to the two point function of a field $\phi^\dagger$ has a combinatorial factor of $1/2$, because we have one way to connect the first field, then the rest is determined.

However this appears to impossible to calculate using an 'arrow method' which I was told was valid in this case. In this method, before we start counting we label arrows on the vertices and external fields which restrict our ability to make connections.

We could say that both fields have an arrow that goes into the diagram, in which case we get a collision of arrows at the loop, which is not allowed (a).

That suggests we should have one ingoing arrow and one outgoing arrow for the external fields (b). But I think this leads to a combinitorial factor of 1, not $1/2$. I've illustrated these two situations in the picture.

Could someone please point out where I've gone wrong?

EDIT: There is an error in the photo, it should be $\frac{2*2}{4} = 1 \neq \frac{1}{2}$.

[image]

Comment: 1 looks correct to me. How much do you trust the person who made the answer sheet?

Comment: Not sure, but if 1/2 is wrong it leads to several other of the answers being wrong, so I expected I was at fault. However, I am completely at a loss to follow the reasoning.

Comment: Yeah :( Unfortunately, I can tell you that it would not be the first time I have seen faculty-level people get symmetry factors wrong recently. I know this kind of thing is very frustrating. If you can correlate the disagreements between the other answers, maybe we can identify one source of the problems.

Comment: FWIW, OP's Feynman diagram (b) with oriented arrows has symmetry factor $S=1$. (With arrows the diagram doesn't have symmetry.)

Comment: Can confirm, also using the "arrow method" I get S = 2 * 2 / 4 = 1.