# Symmetry Factor for Feynman diagram of complex field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, feynman-diagrams, complex-numbers

When studying Feynman diagram I have been told that when treating a complex scalar field we use pertubation which is normalize with factor $1/n$ (where $n$ is the number of terms in the perturbation) instead of $1/n!$ for similar theory but with real scalar field instead of complex.

Using this convention, Is the symmetry factor of Feynman diagram of complex scalar field will be the same if I replace the field with real scalar field (and with the difference of the normalization)?

EDIT: I now think that it is a mistake and it should be someting like $((N/2)!)^2$ and I be happy if somone will be able to verify it

Comment: That does not sound right. Is this from a reference? Which page?

Comment: I only have this written in tutorial page of my course.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/606664/2451